# Finding duplicate values in an array and outputing all of them

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

So I have some working code for outputting duplicate values in an array, however it is always one short when it outputs them on the screen and I know it has to do with the following code, but I just can't put my finger on it. 
Please note I can't use any `System.Array`.

```
for (column = 0; column < WinningScores.Length -1 ; column++) 
{
    if (WinningScores[column] == WinningScores[column + 1]) 
    {
        duplicateScore = WinningScores[column];
        duplicateIndex = column;
        Console.Write("\n Competitor {0} is the Winner with a total of: {1}", 
                      duplicateIndex + 1, 
                      duplicateScore - totalSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Can you please tell us for some sample values what is the output that you are getting and what is expected? It would be easier for us to understand the issue.

Comment: If it's always one short is it something to do with WinningScores.Length -1 ... should it just be WinningScores.Length ?

Comment: its like its missing the last value of the Array "WinningScores"

Comment: @D.Mac I Think it should, and the condition in the `if` should be `column == WinningScores.Length` to check if it is the last iteration

Comment: @remuze WinningScores.Length has an out of bounds error

Comment: Well, doing `Length -1` and combating it with `column + 1` is really weird and seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 how would I put that into my code? at the end?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Would you suggest another way?

Comment: @Diam In your `If ` condition, that would allow you to make a different action for the **last** repetition only. However, you'll want to do something else, you're not checking for duplicates here but for two consecutive values

Comment: How do you want to check for duplicate values? The way you're *attempting* to check for duplicates is just for the next index and not all indices. What if you had an array of `99.0, 85.7, 99.0`? Are yo sorting the array somewhere?

Comment: **"I can't use system.array"**. You really should tell us why we might have to tie our hands behind our backs to solve your problems.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use two for loops.  Your second loop should start at the second element of the array and iterate starting there.  Then when your second for loop iterates again start at the third element, to avoid matching the same elements.  If you want the logic for this I could post it below.

Comment: That would be really kind of you @JPHochbaum Thank you :)

Comment: Ferhi's response was more detailed than mine, but he has the same idea.  This works for small arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Starts loop through first element
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length, i++)

//starts at second element in array
for(int j = i + 1; k < arr.length, j++)

//double check my logic though, in a hurry at work so had to post this in a rush.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using LINQ for this:

```
double[] WinningScores = new double[] { 4, 5, 3, 5 };

var duplicates =
    WinningScores
        .Select((score, index) => new { score, player = index + 1})
        .GroupBy(x => x.score, x => x.player)
        .Where(gxs => gxs.Count() > 1);
```

That gives me this result:

[image: result]

You can see that it picked up the duplicate score of `5` with players `2` & `4`.

Comment: I wonder if OP can't use `System.Array` whether linq might fall into the same category.

Comment: @spender - probably, but he wasn't clear on that or why he couldn't use `System.Array`. It's still a nice answer and SO is for the community, not just the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks for  duplication in consécutive values.
Try this code to output duplicate values in an array.

```
  for (column = 0; column < WinningScores.Length -1 ; column++) 
     {

        for (int cl= column + 1 ; cl < WinningScores.Length - 1 ; cl++)
            {
               if (WinningScores[column] == WinningScores[cl]) {


                        duplicateScore = WinningScores[column];
                        duplicateIndex = column;
                        Console.Write("\n Competitor {0} is the Winner with a total  of: {1}", duplicateIndex + 1, duplicateScore - totalSum);
              }
             }
         }
```